# User-data not working when starting EC2 instance

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to run simple user data by following below link in my company's AWS EC2 server :
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

user data is not working, because there is no file created in tmp/ directory.

user data I am using:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hello World" >> /tmp/testfile.txt
--//--
```

I also tried to print cloud-init.log in var/log/ directory.

error says:

```
2022-05-12 16:46:37,224 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/userdata.txt'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)
2022-05-12 16:46:37,234 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Exec format error. Missing #! in script?
Command: ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/userdata.txt']
Exit code: -
Reason: [Errno 8] Exec format error: b'/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/userdata.txt'
Stdout: -
Stderr: -
2022-05-12 16:46:37,234 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2022-05-12 16:46:37,234 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: modules-final/config-scripts-user: FAIL: running config-scripts-user with frequency always
2022-05-12 16:46:37,234 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
2022-05-12 16:46:37,234 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 1086, in _run_modules
    ran, _r = cc.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cloud.py", line 55, in run
    return self._runners.run(name, functor, args, freq, clear_on_fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/helpers.py", line 185, in run
    results = functor(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py", line 44, in handle
    subp.runparts(runparts_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/subp.py", line 424, in runparts
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Runparts: 1 failures (userdata.txt) in 1 attempted commands
```

I have no clue how to fix this! let me know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

all you need is

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hello World" >> /tmp/testfile.txt
```

in user data. get rid of everything else.

Comment: I also wanted to run this user data when I start the instance everytime, I believe that's the code to do so.

Comment: I tried using your solution, but just that part of the code didn't work. Still same error.

Comment: @ShivamChauhan how did you get this one solved? I am having the same issue however started randomly without any change - the exact same code produced no errors on previous deployments but I am getting the above error.